# ViewHolder for a gridview -- checkbox checked with onclicklistener not working

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a ViewHolder that has 3 textboxs, an image, and a checkbox in a gridview. The problem is that I can't seem capture/trigger onclicklistener after I added the checkbox to this viewholder.
Only the checkbox seems to set to checked or unchecked. If I click on other area that is on image or textbox I want to trigger onClick event.

Also, if someone has clue if we can setclickable to false for a few checkbox, so it can be viewed but not active to respond.

My code at the moment is in the ImageAdpater:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    ImageView imgView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder(); 
            LayoutInflater ltInflate = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ); 
            convertView = ltInflate.inflate(R.layout.griditem, null);

            holder.textview1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_alert_date);
            holder.textview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_alert_time);
            holder.textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_alert_type);

            holder.imageview    = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_ack);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {   
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  Toast.makeText(context, " checkbox checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              } });

        holder.textview1.setText("Text 1 ");
        holder.textview2.setText("Text 2 ");
        holder.textview3.setText("Text 3 ");
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        holder.id = position;

        return convertView;

}
```

Code at the Activity from where imageadpater is called:

```
 GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mygridview);
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {   
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );
```

So the gridview.setOnItemClickListener in the above is not being called, why?
I have tried different setups but nothing seems to work, only checkbox event works and that too if defined in getView as above.

In need of an urgent solution, Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding these lines to the checkbox in the layout xml:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

This does the trick.